# Styling different objects with mapbox studio?

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-studio

I have two highways and want to set different color for them, for example one red and another is green? Is there a way to do that with studio?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You just need to find a unique value for each road segment to symbolize off.  For example you could specify an objectID or a name field for the road segments and then set the color to whatever color you want.  I haven't used Studio for awhile so I don't know what the syntax would look like, but if you follow their guides you should be able to figure it out.  https://www.mapbox.com/help/getting-started-studio-classic/